# C++ array size in main

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am learning c++ and I have these doubts:

I want to initialize the array at run time but the size of array also needs to be read  at run time.

```
int size;

int main(){
    //read size
    size = <value read above>;
    CIwUIButton* buttons[size];
}
```

This does not compile and says `size` must be constant.I come from Java background and I could achieve the same functionality by following same logic.How to do it in c++.

I am using vector as an equivalent to Java ArrayList.I want a reference to vector outside main but want to initialize it inside main.Again max_size will be read from user input and all elements should be initialized to 0;

```
vector<int> elements;

int main(){
    //read size
    int size = <value read above>;
    //how to do following in c++
    elements = new vector<int>(size);
}
```

Comment: You're trying to initialize a non pointer variable with a pointer.

Comment: Global variables are bad too.

Comment: Unlike Java, in C++ you hardly ever need `new`.

Comment: @vishesh In case your CIwUIButton has non-default constructor, you need to initialize each instance with its arguments.

Comment: If you're learning C++, don't fall into the trap of `new`ing everything. You'll get into bad habits of memory management. Use `vector<CIwUIButton>` to hold your array, add using `push_back()`. For the second example, `vector<int> elements; elements.resize(size);` will give you what need and you won't have to manage any memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, so C++ is not Java, and Java is not C++. They are both separate languages.

If you have an unknown number of "things", you need to use either a `vector` or dynamically allocate using `new`. So if you want `size` number of `CIwUIButton` pointers:

```
CIwUIButton** buttons = new CIwUIButton*[size];
```

(Make sure you use `delete [] buttons` later - after deleting each button).

If you want `size` number of buttons:

```
CIwUIButton* buttons = new CIwUIButton[size];
```

Again, use same as above to `delete` the buttons, but you won't need to delete the buttons themselves)

You could also use `vector` for `CIwUIButton`.

If you want size number of integers in a global vector called `elements` then:

```
elements.resize(size);
```

(There is near no situation where you need to call `new` for a `vector` object - that's probably wrong, unless you know exactly why you are doing it)

Comment: By far the most complete and accurate answer here.

Comment: Unfortunately, writing a "long" answer also loses out in the competition for "first answer"... :(

Comment: That's true. But I upvoted you anyway so you'd be right under the accepted one. You should get some visibility out of this.

Comment: Guys, what do you think is missing with my answer (previously accepted one)? not a protest, just a desire to catch what I am missing if any..

Comment: @sgun: The main point, I suppose (from my point of view) is "not using new with vector".

Comment: @MatsPetersson I totally agree with you. I wonder who would use new with vector and why? Anyway, good and informative answer, cheers!

Comment: @sgun I can't think of a situation where you'd want to use `new` to create a vector on its own - but I didn't want to say "never use new with vector", because I'm sure there is some obscure situation where it's necessary... ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part;

you need to allocate array dynamically as follows:

```
CIwUIButton** buttons = new CIwUIButton*[size];
```

*(Do not forget to delete that object and its elements using destructor and delete [].)*

If you want to use non-default constructor you need to initialize each object in a loop:

```
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    buttons[i] = new CIwUIButton(x,y);
 }
```

Second question;

```
 std::vector<int> elements;
```

You do not need to give a size, however you can define a size like this:

```
 elements.resize(size);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, we follow this idiom known as [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).
Resource Acquisition Is Initialization.

When you declare an instance of an object A inside a scope:

```
{
    A instance;
}
```

This object will be destroyed when we leave the scope.

In the case of your global `std::vector<int>`, it will be created and initialized when the program begins execution and it will be deallocated when the program terminates.

There is no need for `new` and `delete` in such a case.

---

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has a `resize` method that allows you to resize the internal array so you can access and modify the elements via `operator[]`. You can also `push_back` or `emplace_back` without having to resize.

Answer (score 0):

For using new you'll just need a `vector<int>*` pointer. The preferred solution for C++ is to use the `vector<T>::resize()` operation:

```
vector<int> elements;

int main(){
    //read size
    int size = <value read above>;
    //how to do following in c++
    elements.resize(size,0);
}
```

Comment: There were two ways you could go with that. Add the pointer as you did, or drop the `new`. Dropping the `new` should be infinitely preferred.

Comment: As he comes from Java background, this answer will suggest to him bad habits. There is no need for new and also elements is never deleted.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector just like this:

```
vector<int> elements;

int main(){
    //read size
    int size = <value read above>;
    //how to do following in c++
    elements.resize(size, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all new objects need to be created with the "new" keyword, but in C++ that is not always the case. elements will be a constructed object by virtue of its declaration, ready to use in main. You can set its size by calling the resize method. Alternatively you can declare elements in main (and not outside as a global variable) and pass the size of the vector as a constructor arguement.

These are basic topics and I suggest you read tutorials on C++ before continuing.

You can make buttons a

```
vector<CIwUIButton *>
```

and set its size in the class constructor. But you will also need to manage how the button elements are created.

Comment: This is not a good solution, the buttons will not be destroyed when the vector is. Either store smart ptrs to them or store the buttons themselves.

Comment: Good point although he never explained where the buttons come from and how they are managed.

Answer (score 0):

Variable length arrays are introduced in C99, but C++ doesn't support it.

To use `vector`:

```
vector<int> elements;

int main(){
    //read size
    int size = <value read above>;
    elements.resize(size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

std::vector doesn't have a fixed size there is no reason to initialize to a specific size, it will just grow on demand. You can do `elements.reserve(size)` which allocates space for the size elements (ints in your example).

> t and all elements should be initialized to 0;

Your elements vector is not a pointer its an Object that is constructed by calling the constructor there is no dynamic memory management needed as it is not even allocated on the heap.

`new` and `delete` (don't forget deletes , or better use smart pointers) are used with pointers only.

example :

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> elements; // not a pointer constructor called because of this statement
  std::vector<int> *elements_ptr = new std::vector<int>(); // this is a pointer pointers have asterisks as part of their declaration and these are initialized via new they simply contain a memory location
  // do stuff here
  delete elements_ptr; // frees allocated memory and calls the destructor for the object 
  return 0;
} // elements destructor is called when it goes out of scope
```

If you are this new to the language I highly recommend reading a book about C++.These are things that are best described by such material.

I would recommend [deitel's how to program C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131857576) or [the C++ programming language by Bjarne Stroustrup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321958322)

Comment: It is better to expand `vector` if you know size, because otherwise values will be copying. It doesn't take so long but anyway, why to waste time.

Answer (score 0):

First I wouldn't use global variables, it is some kind of evil.

If you do not know, how many objects/variables you will need, you have two options, either use some container, or dynamically allocate memory.

I would suggest to use container, but first about dynamical allocation. In C `malloc` and `free` in C++ `new` and `delete`. C type allocation gives you piece of memory and C++ type does the same and calls constructor and destructor, I suggest to use C++ allocators.

How to use it:

```
Object *ptr;         //pointer to some object
ptr = new Object;    //creating one object
delete ptr;          //deleting that object, destructor called and memory deallocated
ptr = new Object[n]; //created n objects, to reach any of them just use array index
delete [] ptr;       //deleted array. n destructors called all memory freed
```

**If you create array of object, do not use `delete` without `[]`.**

So it is about your own allocators. In your case using `vector` is probably the best option. But I'll say it once again, global variables is bad idea. I would recommend to pass a reference to it when you call function.

There are a few ways of function prototypes in C++

```
/*1*/foo(Object obj);    //value of given object will be copied it's slow but sometimes we need that
/*2*/foo(Object *obj);   //passing pointer more C type. Fast but unsafe.
/*3*/foo(Object &obj);   //C++ passing reference. It is the same as passing pointer but it is C++ type declaration, it is safer because you won't pass NULL and you won't go out of memory
/*4*/foo(const Object *obj);
/*5*/foo(const Object &obj);  //Same as before one is C type, another C++ type (unsafe and safer). Keyword `const` means what value won't be changed.
```

Calls to these functions look like this:

```
Object obj;
/*1*/foo(obj);
/*2*/foo(&obj);
/*3*/foo(obj);
/*4*/foo(&obj);
/*5*/foo(obj);
```

So going back to your question.

If you really want to use global variable, so you will need to resize your container. In your case it is `elements.resize(size);` But I wouldn't use global data so my option would be:

```
typedef std::vector<CIwUIButton> ButtonVector;  //in big projects typedef makes us to type less :)
size_t size = <value read above>;
ButtonVector buttons(size);   //You will need default constructor to initialize all buttons
```

I've seen a pointer in your code, not sure, what you wanted to do with that but I think it is not necessary.

BTW you should read about STL containers because C++ and JAVA differs. Especially read about `vector` and `deque`. In your case `vector` is probably better then `deque` but you mentioned `ArrayList` and it is much more `deque` then `vector`.

**EDIT**  If you are really want to start programming with C++ you should also look at `boost` in your case `scoped_array` and `shared_ptr` may be useful.

Answer (score -3):

You have to allocate memory dynamically, use malloc and assign sizeof(yourClass) * size to the pointer you have created

Comment: don't mix mallocs and classes, it doesn't call constructors

Comment: Ok use new! Thats all I mean

Comment: He's using new that's not the problem. Look at the second piece of code.